# Identify unique characters

Tags: mysql, sql, validation

I have a huge load of data and i need to identify for one of the columns i.e., name field if there are special characters being used anything other the A-Z letters and return all that data and maybe the special character as well in a column next to it
Please help

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please tag only the database you are actually using for this requirement. Also review [ask] and follow that as a template for your question.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, Postgresql or SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

On all versions of MySQL, it is easy to flag records for which the column has non `A-Z` characters, using `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT col
FROM yourTable
WHERE col REGEXP '[^A-Z]';
```

If you are using MySQL 8+, then you may use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to remove `A-Z` characters, leaving behind only the special characters in that column.  Modify the above query to this:

```
SELECT
    col,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '[^A-Za-z]+', '') AS col_special
FROM yourTable
WHERE col REGEXP '[^A-Z]';
```